# Disproportional Icon Size in Eclipse

Tags: icons, eclipse

I recently installed the Eclipse IDE (2018-09) for C/C++ on a Mid2014 MacBook on the Ubuntu 16.04 partition. However it is not really usable as the icon size is way too big and takes up to much space. I tried to figure out why but couldn't find anything similar. I also use Eclipse on a Windows machine where I didn't have this problem. Here's a of the standard workspace:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have this problem too, in gtk3 environments with 2x scaling enabled. I have not been able to resolve it. The font and UI components are the correct size, but the icons seem approximately 2x too large. Components like tab titles and menu items with icons (with or without text) are also much larger than they should be, as they grew to accommodate the large icon.